# Determine Size of Pickled Datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pickle

I am currently pickling a python `datetime` to be passed to a task via celery, and am running into memory issues. I'd like to find a way to determine the resulting size of pickling a `datetime` object so that I can compare it to pickling the unix timestamp. I realize the timestamp will be smaller, but I specifically want to compare the sizes of both pickled objects.

Answer (score 3):

A pickled object is just an array of bytes (think ASCII encoded string). So, use `dumps` to get the bytes and look at the length. On my machine, a pickled `datetime` is 44 bytes. This includes some overhead, e.g., it will include a head indicating the pickle protocol version.

```
import datetime
import pickle

dt = datetime.datetime.now()
size = len(pickle.dumps(dt))
print(size, 'bytes')
```

Also, if you use a higher protocol, the resulting pickled object should be smaller.  Try `protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` in the `dump`.

Comment: I found `sys.getsizeof` and this gave me a different result than `print(len(etc))`. `getsizeof` gave me 108 bytes, while `print` gave me 77.

Comment: for fun, add `size2 = len(pickle.dumps(dt,2))`, pickle protocol v2 is quite a bit smaller.

Comment: @paradox870 - getsizeof is the in-memory size of the string object which includes other overhead. len is the count of the number of characters in the string. If you send the string as ascii, it'll be len() bytes long. If you encode in, say, utf-16, it'll twice that.

Comment: @paradox870 `sys.getsizeof` returns the size of the object in memory, not the pickled size (I think).

Comment: @tdelaney @peter-sutton I used `print(len(etc))` on both v1 and v2 of the pickle dumps and received 71 and 44 respectively. I also ran `sys.getsizeof` on both and got back 108 and 88 respectively. This pickled information is being stored in a redis instance used for my celery queue. Which one is more accurate to the size used in the redis queue?

Comment: While in-memory as a python object, getsizeof would be the better indicator. In transit or in a redis cache, I'm not really sure, except that I think that redis is quite a bit leaner with integers. Be aware that unix timestamps, if expressed as a signed 32 bit integer will overflow in the next couple of decades and should be avoided. Kinda a mini Y2K.

Comment: @paradox870 if you're sending pickled `datatime`s to Celery then the length of the pickled string (`print(len(...))`) is what you're interested in.